# nodejs how to upload image from API

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I am new to node JS and i have made function for uploading image from API.
But when i hit the URL from postman using form-data having field name image then in response it shows me.
[Here is the postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArOfk.png)

> Error uploading file

below is my code

My router.js contain:-

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

var ctrlSteuern = require('../controllers/steuern.controllers.js');
```

router

```
 .route('/steuern/image_upload')
 .post(ctrlSteuern.imageUpload);
```

in Controller i have:-

```
var multer = require('multer'); 

var multiparty = require('multiparty');

var storage =   multer.diskStorage({

destination: function (req, file, callback) {

callback(null, './image');

},

filename: function (req, file, callback) {

callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());

}

});

var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('image');

module.exports.imageUpload = function(req, res){

upload(req,res,function(err) {

if(err) {

return res.end("Error uploading file.");

}

return res.end("File is uploaded");

});

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my code for saving image to folder.

```
exports.saveMedia = (req, res) => {
        const storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: (req, file, callback) => {
                callback(null, (config.const.path.base + config.const.path.productReviewMedia));
            },
            filename: (req, file, callback) => {
                callback(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
            }
        });

        const upload = multer({storage: storage}).any('file');

        upload(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: helper.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            }
            let results = req.files.map((file) => {
                return {
                    mediaName: file.filename,
                    origMediaName: file.originalname,
                    mediaSource: 'http://' + req.headers.host + config.const.path.productReviewMedia + file.filename
                }
            });
            res.status(200).json(results);
        });
}
```

[image]

Here is post man request.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply but int his code when i try to console.log req.files then cmd is showing it as undefined.

Comment: const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, callback) => {
            callback(null, './image');
        },
        filename: (req, file, callback) => {
            callback(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
        }
    });

Comment: upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: helper.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        }
        console.log(req.files);
        let results = req.files.map((file) => {
            return {
                mediaName: file.filename,
                origMediaName: file.originalname
            }
        });
        res.status(200).json(results);
    });

Comment: const upload = multer({storage: storage}).any('file'); put this line.

Comment: i have putted this line but same issue is coming

Comment: i have edited my answer in which you will find the image of postman